# error message box cox in proc transreg procedure in sas

Tags: sas, transformation

I try to use the `proc transreg` procedure in SAS, to transform one of my variables in a dataset (`var1`). The var1 variable has `values >=0`.

My code is:

```
proc transreg data=data1 details;
model boxcox(var1/lambda=-1 to 1 by 0.125 convenient parameter=1)=identity(var2);
output out=BoxCox_Out;
run;
```

However I get the following error message:

"observation of nonblank *TYPE* not equal 'Score ' are excluded from the analysis and the output data set.

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_TYPE_` can be used for `TRANSREG` to allow you to take datasets with multiple kinds of rows and only use the SCORE rows (or whichever ones you choose), often outputs from earlier `TRANSREG` procedures.

However, `_TYPE_` is also a common variable added by procedures like `PROC MEANS` to indicate which class combinations apply to the row.  In this case, `TRANSREG` is getting confused and thinking you want something different.

Drop the `_TYPE_` variable in the `TRANSREG` data source statement, and it should use all rows.

```
proc transreg data=data1(drop=_type_) details;
```